# Firebase rules: permission denied

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to restrict user access to some high-level node but want to give some users ability to read some of the subnodes.

My data structure is like that:

```
{
  "COMPANIES" : {
    "COMPANY1" : {
      "id" : "COMPANY1",
      "name" : "COMPANY1 COMPANY"
    },
    "COMPANY2" : {
      "id" : "COMPANY2",
      "name" : "COMPANY2 COMPANY"
    }
  },

  "USERS" : {
    "xZgFtwVyQFsPK3428YCa3NekOEF3" : {
      "company" : {
        "COMPANY1" : true,
        "COMPANY2" : true
      },
      "email" : "ss@sss.com",
      "uid" : "xZgFtwVyQFsPK3428YCa3NekOEF3",
      "username" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

and so on.

And my rules for this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "USERS": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },

    "COMPANIES": {
      "COMPANY1": {
        ".read": "root.child('USERS').child(auth.id).child('company').child('COMPANY1').val() == true",
        ".write": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code I'm using to access this data looks like that (in Swift):

```
refFire.child("COMPANIES").child("COMPANY1").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (dsnap) in
```

Also, I tried this one:

```
refFire.child("COMPANIES").queryOrdered(byChild: "COMPANY1").queryEqual(toValue: "COMPANY1").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (dsnap) in
```

And this one (unfortunately, I don't really understand the idea behind `queryEqual`, so I've tried different approaches):

```
refFire.child("COMPANIES").child("COMPANY1").queryOrdered(byChild: "COMPANY1").queryEqual(toValue: "COMPANY1").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (dsnap) in
```

So I want to give access to COMPANY1 to users with `COMPANY1 = true` in their profile (and deny everyone else). Rules seemed to be relatively straightforward but obviously I'm doing something wrong here because even users with `COMPANY1 = true` can't read company information, the permission is denied.

Comment: 1) Please edit your question to include the minimum code that reproduces the error message. 2) It would also help to see the actual JSON, instead of a schematic representation of it. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Node names are case sensitive, so `root.child('users')` does not match `/USERS` that you use everywhere else.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks a lot. I've made some corrections to the question. Regarding users/USERS – I've found this error after I posted the question (but thanks again) but the permission denied is still here.

Comment: At first glance that first read operation should work, as long as the UID is correct. If you log the UID right before the read operation, what does it print? Please show both the updated code and its output,

Comment: The second and third reads won't work, because security rules don't filter your data for you. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules